# Disowned command with redirected STDOUT/STDERR still sending output to shell

Tags: bash, io-redirection, bashrc, nohup, disown

I defined a function in my `.bashrc` that allows me to open e.g. pdf files from bash by running `copen myfile.pdf`:

```
function copen {
    if [[ $# -eq 1 ]] ; then
        xdg-open "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown
        return 1
    fi
}
```

By running this command, I execute e.g. Okular in the background, redirect STDOUT and STDERR to `/dev/null` and disown it from bash. However, after running `copen myfile.pdf` I still get output printed to bash (`QSqlQuery::exec: database not open` multiple times) and I don't understand why. How do I suppress that kind of output?

*Note that the problem persists when changing the code to* `nohup xdg-open "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1 &`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

copen() {
    (($# == 1)) && xdg-open "$1" &>/dev/null & disown
}
copen "$1"
```

Run the script as follows:  `./myscript SomePDFfile.pdf`

The `&>/dev/null` is a shorthand for `>/dev/null 2>&1` added in bash >4.

The `copen` function needs a parameter.

Comment: Some explenation?

Comment: I keep getting the same output to my shell, `QSqlQuery::exec: database not open`.

Comment: @cbaumhardt Does  `xdm-open somefile.pdf`  open correctly from the terminal?

Comment: @val0x00ff: Bash doesn't know the command `xdm-open`. If I just enter `xdg-open myfile.pdf` in bash, the pdf opens correctly and a lot of overhead is printed in bash.

Comment: @cbaumhardt  sorry I meant `xdg-open`  from the command line on your terminal.  If you have problems with your path try `/usr/bin/xdg-open "$1"` within the script.

Comment: I think `xdg-open` works fine, I do not have problems with it cause when I just enter `xdg-open myfile.pdf` it chooses Okular to open my pdf, displays the pdf correctly and I get the following reply: http://paste.debian.net/884568/. By using my code from above or your code from above, I still get `QSqlQuery::exec: database not open` as a reply and I don't understand why this output is not suppressed.

Comment: Have you selected your preferred application to be `ocular` for opening `pdf` files?

Comment: Yes, `okular` is my preferred application for opening pdfs.

Comment: This does exactly the same output redirections as the function in the question?

Comment: Yes. And it also has the same output as just running `okular myfile.pdf > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown`. I don't understand why there is output at all if I redirect both stdout and stderr.

Comment: Your code as well as my original code was right from the very start, it just didn't work because made a very stupid mistake: I didn't source the code changes correctly, because I am new to using a recently installed bash framework (https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it). I am so sorry for this and happily will accept your answer (which works, just like my initial code).

Comment: @cbaumhardt  glad you solved it and thank you for the feedback.